# Limit access to registration page. How to make it available only for not authenticated users?

Tags: django, django-views

I have registration page and use default login:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

But question is how to make it available only for not authenticated users?
For registration page (for which I have view) I'm trying to make

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
   ...
else:
   redirect(...)
```

So what to do with login page?
Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I was also having same problem like this but the LoginView have a attribute -> redirect_authenticated_user

> redirect_authenticated_user: A boolean that controls whether or not authenticated users accessing the login page will be redirected as if they had just successfully logged in. Defaults to False.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views

url(r'^login/$', views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='account/login.html', redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),
```

and it will prevent the user to go to login page,

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just raise 404 not found error:

```
from django.http import Http404
    # ..... 
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        raise Http404 ('Not Available')
    else:
        # ....
```